# Save OneHot Encoder object python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Is there anyway of saving OneHotencoder object in python? . Reason is being I used that object in preprocessing of training data and test data and we are building a API containing the same trained model and that will be injected by real data from the website when user created. So first that data needs to be preprocessed and then model can predict o/p for the same.

Thanks

Comment: Have you used `sklearn`'s `joblib.dump` and `load` functions?

Comment: Since I am using keras model, I am able to save model and save weight . Problem is with preprocessing of data. I want to retain my OHE object so that i can transform unseen data.

Comment: Is the preprocessor part of keras or not? If it is a scikit model, read this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Comment: Yeap It helped.simple use of  pickel for OHE will do for me.

Comment: I recommended `joblib`, the second example there because it has some advantages to it (such as parallellization).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

simple use of pickel for OHE will do for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate on it?